# VS Code - Opening side bar doesn't navigate/seed

Tags: visual-studio-code

In older versions of VS Code this worked, but I assume some setting changed or something...

If I select some text, and then press CTRL+SHIFT+F to open Search in the side bar, it opens, but does not change the search to match my selected text.  If I do the same thing when Search is already open, it works

Similarly, if I CTRL+Click on a folder path when Explorer is not open, it opens Explorer but doesn't select the folder.  If I CTRL+Click with Explorer already opened, it works

Is there a setting or some tweak that controls this, or should I file a bug report?

Comment: Sounds like it could be a bug. What are the values of `explorer.autoReveal` and `search.seedOnFocus` in your settings, and do you get any different, desirable behaviour if you change to different values?

Comment: ah, seedOnFocus was disabled!  I found the similar setting for the search widget, but not for the side bar search.

explorer.autoReveal does what I'd expect for a folder...  when it's turned off, which seems backwards.  That definitely seems like the setting I'd expect though, so I'll submit a bug about it.

Comment: If you submit an issue ticket, please edit your post to add a link to it for posterity. I'm interested in following the discussion there.

Comment: Will do.  This is a bit of a two part question it turns out since half was working as intended, do you want to make an answer for that that I can accept, or should I wait until I see how the bug goes?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/176570

Comment: The thing is, I actually cannot reproduce either of your issues. Whether or not my sidebar is opened to the search tab, if I select text in my current editor and press ctrl+shift+f, the search bar open seeded with the selected text, even if I set `"search.seedOnFocus": false`. I would report that as an issue too. (please add a link here so I can subscribe to it)